# Can I downgrade Vscode without losing my extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to downgrade Vscode without losing all my extensions?

I already have the specific install file with the version that I need. Should I uninstall Vscode before installing the downgraded version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/itemdetails?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync it allows you to sync your settings across multiple devices, which means you wont ever lose it. Its settings requires like 2-3minutes, but after that you can safely delete vscode and install anyother version, plus its very handy if you run normal version of vscode and preview-version